# How to correctly use ShowDialog method in this case?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have problem with Windows Forms.
When I show form2 from form1 like this (names of the variables changed):

```
form2.ShowDialog(form1);
```

then I have this exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog
box. Set the form's visible property to false before calling showDialog.
```

Telling more - during debugging I see that after calling ShowDialog method debugger goes again to the same ShowDialog method - and this is why I have this exception. I suppose that form1 is loaded again and it is some kind of ShowDialog method bug? I have form2 Visible property set to false. I tried to use Hide method too - not working.

Edit:
More info - I use ShowDialog method after showing combo box selector from form1. When I click the last property in combo box by mouse - ShowDialog is working. If I go down by keyboard and click 'Enter' mentioned exception appears.

Comment: call `form2.ShowDialog()`

Comment: You are not looking for form2.show(this); ?

Comment: you are trying to Show form1 again not the form2

Comment: Sorry, mistake in code. I call form2.ShowDialog(form1);

Comment: you're doing it wrong if you want to show the form2
'form2.ShowDialog()' is the correct way on showing form

Comment: You need to show the complete code surrounding this call, the code you have provided shows no errors in it

Comment: There is no bug in the `ShowDialog` method. You need to show more code and give more information.

Comment: There was too much much code to paste, I would have to paste here few classes from my company product.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. When you close Form2, control will go back to Form1 (or whoever called Form2):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help vmgmail :) I made as you told and I have no more exceptions. I have another strange behaviour now - 2 forms of  type 'form2' are showed after I call ShowDialog.

Comment: Add a breakpoint on `form2.ShowDialog()` and see how many times it stops there.

Comment: Something's going on beyond scope of the problem. The fact that you're using `ShowDialog()` means that it shows the Form as a modal dialog box, which means that you can't access the parent Form until you close Form2.

Answer (score 0):

Or just

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    new form2().ShowDialog();
}
```